# Is this flowchart's logic correct?

Tags: new-operator, flowchart

[This is my flow chart for a clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drt4B.png)

This clock is suppose to show time and reset when it turns 24 hours, may i know if all the shapes ive used in this flowchart is correct? thanks

Comment: We're not here to mark your homework. If you have a specific problem then please focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong.

Because if sec not equal 60 you must increase sec and loop from begin